# Select rows up to specific value

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Is there a way to select from first row up to the specific row that matches a condition?

Example:

```
Date        Val or Val
1-1-2018    2      s 
1-2-2018    3      q 
1-3-2018    4      l 
1-4-2018   -2      a 
1-5-2018   -4      a 
1-6-2018   -6      c
```

I need only to select up to the first negative

```
value: 2 3 4 -2
```

or up to first **a** : s q l a

Note. As much as possible I prefer not to use subquery. If only possible

Comment: Tables rows are not stored in order. Unless you have a sorting key, what you ask for is not possible.

Comment: Only if there is another column which defines the order those values should be evaluated.

Comment: it is sorted by date btw. I forgot to mention

Comment: then if is sorted  by date .updated  your question and add  a coherent data sample .. .

Comment: Please edit your question to explain that show and to suitable dates in your sample data. It might help if you include some context for what you are really trying to do, as this sounds part of a bigger query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pretty much need a subquery.

I would be inclined to do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date <= (select min(t2.date)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.val1 < 0 or t2.val3 = 'a'
                );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when val1 < 0 or val2 = 'a' then date end) over (order by date) as cutoff_date
      from t
     ) t
where date <= cutoff_date;
```

I should be careful.  In Oracle 12C, you could do this without a subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
order by coalesce(sum(case when val1 < 0 or val2 = 'a' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0)
fetch first 1 row only with ties;
```

But this approach is a bit abstruse.